# Delete using RemoveRange when FK exists

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know this comes up a lot, but I am wondering about how I am getting my list of entities which to delete has any impact on being successful or not.

In the code below, Im getting an error complaining about conflicting FK constraint.
In this case the table PaymentInvoice as a FK reference to WarehouseStatementBatchPayment which in turn has an FK referece to WarehouseStatementBatch.  So I should be able to delete records from the child table (PaymentInvoice in this case).  I could understand if I was deleting from one of the other tables, since records in PaymentInvoice would still refer to those I was deleting.  Not so in this case?

Since Im fetching my list of PaymentInvoice records by joining on the other two, does this affect my ability to delete them?

```
                        var PaymentInvoiceList = (from b0 in ctx.PaymentInvoices
                                                    join c0 in ctx.WarehouseStatementBatchPayments on b0.WarehouseStatementBatchPaymentID equals c0.ID
                                                    join d0 in ctx.WarehouseStatementBatches on c0.WarehouseStatementBatchID equals d0.ID
                                                    where d0.ID == b0.ID
                                                    select b0)
                                            .ToList();
                        ctx.PaymentInvoices.RemoveRange(PaymentInvoiceList);
```

The error I get:
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_PaymentInvoice_WarehouseStatementBatchPayment\"

That FK exists in the PaymentInvoice table.

Also, I checked for any other possible dependencies on the PaymentInvoice table and there were none (other than some views and stored procedures).  Some of the stored procedures have been pulled into the Data model as function imports, but thats not the immediate concern as evident by the error message only complaining about an FK constraint.

What else should I check?

Comment: have you checked with a profiler which delete command was send to sql server ? It sounds like EF is constructing a different delete statement than you are expecting.

Comment: Good suggestion.  After runnning profiler, tt seems its generating delete statements against the  WarehouseStatementBatchPayments table first, which would explain the FK constraint error.

Comment: Oh wow, I just discovered an issue with the query itself.   where d0.ID == b0.ID is wrong, I meant to use a specific value here. Thanks again for the suggestion to use profiler.  This let me discover stuff that should NOT have been happening that was in fact happening.  Once I started looking for the reason, I spotted a problem with my query.

Comment: no problem, I find that I am also sometimes looking over the obvious until someone looks at it with a clean point of view

Comment: note:  anyone else finding this thread - if your getting FK constraint errors yet you are deleting child entities, then double-check your selection.  You might just be selecting more than you think or the wrong list.